# convexity of Inf function

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove the following function is convex \
h(u)=inf { f(x)+g(Ax+u)}
\  inf is over x, I tried to use epi graph definition  but I failed because there is no assumprion for f and g being convex. can I use this face it h(x) is just a function of a linear variable like y that is bigger than the statement in above {}

thanks.

Comment: You have to state the question clearly. Specify the values taken by all the variables.

Comment: the only condition here is that f and g are from E to minus and plus infinity and A is a linear map. inf is taken over x in E.  nothing more

Comment: There is nothing in the hypothesis that makes h real-valued. It can take the value $-\infty$.

Comment: Exactly, it can take any number in R, How can then prove that it is a  convex function?

Comment: I believe that the statement is false. In one dimension if f(x)=-sinx, g(x)=sinx and a=1  we can compute h and it turns out that h is not convex.

Comment: it is the theorem 3.3.5 of convex analysis   by Borwein